# Keyword hierarchy in robot framework

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I would like to ask, what is the best way to organize keywords in robot framework. I am using robot framework to test backend application using rest interface. I have multiple keywords stored in robot files, separated based on type of service (equipment, link, etc.), which they should handle. My problem is that I have some high level keywords (operation like create, update, delete, activate some configuration), which are directly called by test cases and also some low level keywords, which are called by high level keywords. My problem is that if these high level keywords are stored together with low level keywords in one file, then it is hard to identify high level keywords from low level keywords. I was thinking of splitting these keywords to separate files, high level keywords into one file and low level keywords into second file.

`EquipmentKeywords.resource`

```
*** Keywords ***
Create equipment
    Low Level Keyword 1
    Low Level Keyword 2
    Low Level Keyword 3

Update equipment
    Low Level Keyword 2
    Low Level Keyword 4
    Low Level Keyword 5
```

`EquipmentLowLevelKeywords.resource`

```
*** Keywords ***
Low Level Keyword 1
    Step 1
    Step 2
    Step 3

Low Level Keyword 2
    Step 1
    Step 2
    Step 3
...
```

What do you think would be a good approach to this problem?
Thank you.